# Display exception message after encountering an exception

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, web-applications

I have a program that reads the amount entered

If the user enters a non numeric input,

```
try {
    number = Convert.ToDouble(input);
}
catch (Exception ex) {
    Response.Redirect(Request.RawUrl);
    Label1.Text = ex.Message;
}
```

But the exception message doesn't show when the page is refreshed. IS there a better way to do this?

Thanks.

Comment: It will not show exception message, as you are redirectiong to somewhere else on exception

Comment: @Pawan I'm redirecting to the same page i.e. effectively refreshing the page

Comment: The whole page (including any kind of exception) is refreshed, so for the machine it´s a completly new request. Btw.: why do you actually need such a refresh?

Comment: @jay Why are you redirecting to same page using that way? Response.Redirect() will send you to a new page(Same page here) and whole page is reinitialized instead of simple postback

Comment: @HimBromBeere i don't need a refresh, just need to display the message and stop further execution of the program i.e. re-read user input